# MySQL gssapi plugin groans and moans when doing mysql_install_db as non-root

Tags: mysql, installation, mariadb, gssapi

I'm running Fedora 24 and have MariaDB 15.1 Distrib 10.1.24-MariaDB 64-bit installed. I'm a non-root user, and I want to set up a DB of my own. So, I followed the instructions in the answers to:

[Mysql without root privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38234672/1593077)

When I execute

```
mysql_install_db --datadir=$HOME/dbfarms/mysql
```

It does finish, but gives the following warnings/errors (filtering timestamps out):

```
[Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45883
[Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
[Warning] mysqld: GSSAPI plugin : default principal 'mariadb/sofia.da.cwi.nl@' not found in keytab
[ERROR] mysqld: Server GSSAPI error (major 851968, minor 2529639093) : gss_acquire_cred failed -Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information. Keytab FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab is nonexistent or empty. 
[ERROR] Plugin 'gssapi' init function returned error.
OK
Filling help tables...

[Warning] mysqld: GSSAPI plugin : default principal 'mariadb/sofia.da.cwi.nl@' not found in keytab
[ERROR] mysqld: Server GSSAPI error (major 851968, minor 2529639093) : gss_acquire_cred failed -Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information. Keytab FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab is nonexistent or empty. 
[ERROR] Plugin 'gssapi' init function returned error.
OK
Creating OpenGIS required SP-s...

[Warning] mysqld: GSSAPI plugin : default principal 'mariadb/sofia.da.cwi.nl@' not found in keytab
[ERROR] mysqld: Server GSSAPI error (major 851968, minor 2529639093) : gss_acquire_cred failed -Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information. Keytab FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab is nonexistent or empty. 
[ERROR] Plugin 'gssapi' init function returned error.
OK
```

I can obviously not control `/etc/krb5.keytab`. Is there something else I should be doing? Should I disable this plugin somehow? I'll mention this is not a production environment, and there isn't really any sensitive data that's going into the DB, so I can cut some corners security-wise if it helps.

Comment: does anything change if you run mysql_install_db as root?

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub: I don't have root access on that machine.

Comment: ok,  so "as non-root" in description might not be necessarily an essential detail?

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub: It's been there to begin with... :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple workaround - disable the GSSAPI plugin:

```
/path/to/mysql_install_db --gssapi=OFF
```

Note: make sure this doesn't conflict with settings in your `~/.my.cnf` or `/etc/my.cnf`.